# Display Access data with image paths in Word document

Tags: image, ms-access, ms-word, vba, word-wrap

I would like to make a Word product catalog from data stored in an Access 2007 database. I can of course use the "mail merge" function in Word for the text data, but I dont know how to make the images show up! They are they stored as file paths in Access and jpg-files in a directory on the hard drive. The images should have a special size, be right aligned to the text paragraphs so that the text is wrapping on the left side (see attached image).

[image]

Comment: Could you use a report to generate this or do you require Word?

Comment: I can't make the text wrap along the images in Access report, It doesn't seem to have that funcationality. Thats why I go for Word. Wrapping saves a lot of space and make it look better.

Comment: I've kind of given upp the above issue since it seems too difficult and looking now for a way to retrieve single postdata from the 2007 Access database through a vb sub, for example like getProductName(28), where 28 is the product ID in the database. Does anyone know how to write that sub in vb?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, but works better in older versions of Word. Unfortunately, you don't mention which version you're using...

Anyway, the key to the question is to use an IncludePicture field to bring the picture in; pass the file path to the field using the MergeField (nested fields). You can find more information on the internet, for example: http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/mergfaq1.htm#DBPic

The problem with an IncludePicture field is that it can't be wrapped. But if your version of Word is not too old, tables CAN wrap, so you put the IncludePicture field into a table that's a single cell. Position the table, wrap it, etc.